# langchain's chroma `vectordb.similarity_search_with_score()` and `vectordb.similarity_search_with_relevancy_scores()` returns the same output

Tags: nlp, langchain

I have been working with langchain's chroma vectordb. It has two methods for running similarity search with scores.

1. `vectordb.similarity_search_with_score()`
2. `vectordb.similarity_search_with_relevance_scores()`

According to the documentation, the first one should return a cosine distance in `float`.
[image]

Smaller the better.

And the second one should return a score from 0 to 1, 0 means dissimilar and 1 means similar.
[image]

But when I tried the same it is giving me exactly same results with same scores which overflows the upperlimit 1, which should not be the case for the second function.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 8):

Is you are using Chroma, you should set the distance metric when creating a collection: https://docs.trychroma.com/usage-guide#changing-the-distance-function

The default distance is l2. That is why for me it used to give scores like `3626.016357421875` when using the function `similarity_search_with_relevance_scores()`. On changing it to `cosine`, the scores are now between (0, 1] with scores closer to 1 depicting higher similarity.

```
Chroma.from_documents(documents=documents, embedding=cohere, collection_metadata={"hnsw:space": "cosine"})
```

Comment: I was getting similarity scores of 0 for everything until I changed the collection metric to `cosine`. Now it works. Yay.

Comment: Sorry, but does this method actually work? In my case it didn't change anything. It keeps using squared euclidean as metric. 

cosine_db = Chroma.from_texts(['I like apples', 'I watched a movie last night'], embedding=embedding_model, collection_metadata={"hnsw:space":"cosine"}) 
cos_query = embedding_model.embed_query('Did you watch a movie?') 
doc_emb = embedding_model.embed_query('I watched a movie last night')

print(cosine_db.similarity_search_with_score('Did you watch a movie?', k=1))
ssd.cosine(cos_query, doc_emb)

It keeps giving me the wrong metric. I checked with scipy.

Answer (score 5):

I have experienced this issue as follows:

`vectordb.similarity_search()` and `vectordb.similarity_search_with_score()` return exactly the same **top n chucks** in the same order. `similarity_search_with_score()` also has score data. I think this data is important for filtering out irrelevant chucks.

On the other hand, I have read that the `vectordb.similarity_search_with_relevance_scores()` method is more sophisticated and requires more processing to calculate the similarity score, but I got exactly the same results nearly same duration with `vectordb.similarity_search_with_score()` method in dozens of comparisons.

Another issue that caught my attention in this regard is **the meaning of the scores** returned as a result of both methods! [In the official document](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/vectorstores/integrations/chroma), it is stated that the smaller the score, the higher the similarity. I also read that the range of the score is between -1 and 1.

In my tests, I got different scores. For example some unrelated results with 1.9, 2.03 and 0.03 ...

**What is the reason of this?** Why get i a score like 1.9?

I am using ChromaDB as a vectorDB and ChromaDB normalizes the embedding vectors before indexing and searching as a **defult**!. So with default usage we can get 1.9 after the normalization.To get back similarity scores in the -1 to 1 range, we need to disable normalization with `normalize_embeddings=False` while creating the ChromaDB instance.

I can say with my experience that with normalization **scores between 0.6-1.2 have higher similarity**.

Comment: during my testing , I found that the score 0.07 0.09 .0.05 is more similarity, and unrelated results with 0.22 0.23.   langchain + redis.

Answer (score 4):

In official documentation its cosine distance and not cosine similarity.

Cosine Similarity: Measures the cosine of the angle between vectors, indicating their similarity. Higher values mean greater similarity.

Cosine Distance: Measures the dissimilarity between vectors as the complement of the cosine similarity. Higher values mean greater dissimilarity.

```
cosine_similarity(A, B) = (A . B) / (||A|| * ||B||)
cosine_distance(A, B) = 1 - cosine_similarity(A, B)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the solution is not clear, Chroma defaults to using the L2 distance, which has a range of 0-2. To adapt this to Langchain's required relevance score, a Euclidean conversion function is employed. However, this conversion inaccurately uses the square root of 2 in the denominator, not accounting for the squared distance (causing the relevance scores to go negative). To correctly align the relevance score from 0-1 as needed, you should initialize the Chroma class with a customized relevance converter function. Simply use `relevance_score_fn=lambda distance: 1.0 - distance / 2` to ensure proper scaling and direction.